# Callback not firing on resize within React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, resize, react-hooks

I get the console log to fire inside the hook on each resize however the console log that's in the callback that gets passed into the resize hook never fires.

Here is the hook i have which uses useCallbacks per the exhaustive deps eslint plugin:

```
// @flow
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

let resizeId: AnimationFrameID;

export const useResize = (callbackFn: Function, ref?: any) => {
  const resizeUpdate = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('inside');
    callbackFn();
  }, [callbackFn]);

  const handleResize = useCallback(() => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(resizeId);
    resizeId = requestAnimationFrame(resizeUpdate);
  }, [resizeUpdate]);

  const handleOrientation = useCallback(() => {
    // After orientationchange, add a one-time resize event
    const afterOrientationChange = () => {
      handleResize();
      // Remove the resize event listener after it has executed
      window.removeEventListener('resize', afterOrientationChange);
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', afterOrientationChange);
  }, [handleResize]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof ResizeObserver === 'function' && ref && ref.current) {
      let resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => handleResize());
      resizeObserver.observe(ref.current);

      return () => {
        if (!resizeObserver) {
          return;
        }

        resizeObserver.disconnect();
        resizeObserver = null;
      };
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
      window.addEventListener('orientationchange', handleOrientation);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', handleOrientation);
        cancelAnimationFrame(resizeId);
      };
    }
  }, [callbackFn, handleOrientation, handleResize, ref]);
};

export default useResize;
```

Here is how you use it within a component:

```
...
const setContentRef = () => {
  console.log('resize');
};

useResize(setContentRef);
...
```

Comment: where you pass the function setContentRef to useResize have you tried to pass it from an anonymous function?

useResize(()=>{setContentRef()})

Comment: @TaylorBurke yea and still nothing, however i just tested my code outside of my repo in a Code Sandbox and it works as is... so it has to be something else in the code. https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-breeze-dru72